# Displaying an alert box on a Web page?

Tags: jquery

Below is the code where I intend  to dispay an alert box from inside a data table. Is there some special way I need to refer to the datatable?

```
oTable=$("#Administrators").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true, 
    "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:8080/strutsdemo/AdministratorAction.do",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "fnServerdata": function(sSource,aoData,fnCallback){

    /*var Administrator_nm = $("#select1").val();                
      var startswith = $("#select2").val();
      var txt = $("#txt").val();
      alert(txt); */

    var txt=$("#txtName");
    alert(txt.val());
```

Comment: You should put the entire call in there in case there's a syntax error.  As it is, the fnServerdata function is not closed and neither is the dataTable call.

Comment: how should we call the datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

Like all html components, you can use the id attribute on the individual component (your datatable) e.g., `id="myTable"` Then query it:

```
$("#myTable")...
```